# Get grid from parent window to click in child form

Tags: extjs

Hello i am have form with grid and button, and when i am click button then open new form with edit records in grid. But how refer to grid from child window.
I am make this but have error:

```
Pricebook: function(button) {
var win = button.up('window'), 
grid = win.down('grid');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext.getCmp Component id. Take a look at this example:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/850

Comment: Can I use the name property instead of id property?